# horizontal rule doesn't align with each column in orgmode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

I want to create a table on emacs orgmode, but table horizontal rule doesn't align with the column.(by the way, i'm using spacemacs 26).

Step1:
input "| Week Starting | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thurs | Fri | Sat | Sun |"

Step2:
input "|-" and then press "return"

[image: now it looks]
[image: it should look]

Comment: what font are you using?

Comment: You need a fixed-width font for table alignment.

Comment: @NickD yes, as soon as I change it to fixed-width font, it works like a magic!!! thank you